# Passportjs facebook authentication is blocking my application

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

Modules:

```
"express": "~3.0.0",
"jade": ">= 0.0.1",
"mongoose": ">= 3.6.2",
"connect-mongo": "0.3.2",
"nodemailer": ">= 0.3.20",
"socket.io": "0.9",
"cookie": "0.0.5",
"passport": "0.2.3",
"passport-facebook": "*",
"underscore": "*"
```

-- BACKEND --

Expressjs Configuration:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', config.root + '/app/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.limit('1mb'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser(''));
    app.use(express.session());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'public')));

    // express/mongo session storage
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: '',
        store: new mongoStore({
            url: config.db,
            collection : 'sessions'
        })
    }));

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    app.use(app.router);
});
```

In routers:

```
app.get('/login/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { display: 'popup', scope: [ 'email', 'user_about_me'], failureRedirect: '/' }));
app.get('/login/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/' }), user.callbackLogin);
```

In user.callbackLogin :

```
exports.callbackLogin = function(req, res){
    res.render('callback_login');
};
```

callback_login view has a js script to close the window login popup.

-- FRONTEND --

```
Utils.popupCenter = function(url, width, height, name) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(height/2);

    return window.open(url, name, "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width="+width+",height="+height+",toolbar=no,left="+left+",top="+top);
};

Utils.popupCenter('login/facebook', 600, 400, 'Facebook Login');
```

I'm having troubles with passportjs integration. The popup works, the facebook login is called, and when I click in 'Ok' the facebook returns the data and passport saves in mongodb. But, after this point, nothings works. Expressjs blocking the requests. When I try access another url nodejs stay busy. After spends some time I'm receiving the message "No data received".

Comment: Same question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021090/node-passport-facebook-login-in-facebook-page-tab-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's quite late for an answer, but try this project that I put up together:

https://github.com/rafaelfaria/PassportJS-Facebook-Client-Auth

I hope that's what you are looking for.