# Node Passport-facebook login in Facebook Page Tab application

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm developing a web application in NodeJS and AngularJS, that is a PageTab application to facebook.

For the login I'm using the library [Passport-facebook](http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/).

My middleware is:

```
passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        display: 'popup',
        scope: ['read_stream', 'publish_actions', 'email', 'user_photos']
    })
```

The application works if i'm outside the tab of facebook, but when I try into facebook tab, 
I get an error:

```
[Error] Refused to display'Http....'in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. (login, line 0)
[Error] SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

Because `facebook permission dialog` can't be launched from an iFrame

What can I do to fix, keeping the session management with passport strategy?

Comment: The login dialog can not be displayed inside any kind of (i)frames for security reasons – it has to be called in the top window instance. If the framework you are using does not provide a way to achieve that, then I think your only option is to “get out” of the page tab iframe yourself before triggering login (using `top.location.href="…"`), do login while in the top window instance, and redirect back to the page tab address afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, Also I've Done So , and I was hoping it was a good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

At the end what I did:

- When user is not logged in, instead of res.redirect("/auth/facebook"); I did res.render("authorize");
- in the `authorize.html` page I have `window.top.location = window.location + "auth/facebook";`
- an instead of `Passport.authenticate("facebook", { successRedirect: "/", failureRedirect: "/login" } )` I did `Passport.authenticate("facebook", { successRedirect: appHomePage, failureRedirect: appHomePage } )` with `appHomePage` set to the absolute URL of the facebook app (e.g. `https://apps.facebook.com/8480657996/`

Note that it is useful to use environment vars to aviod hard coding the app home page in your app

Comment: Thanks! Your feedback was important to me, got my app working in a tab thanks to you :)